# How come my constructor will not compile in Java if I try and pass an array as an argument in a different public class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor, public

I'm trying to compile this code but keep getting the error-
Error: /Users/Pedro/Dropbox/school/java/Proj/exam 3/EchoText.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor MultiPoint(java.lang.Double[])
location: class MultiPoint

If I omit the array in the constructor for the public EchoText it will compile. However, I need it to pass the array as an argument into the MultiPoint public class. My questions is why won't it compile with the argument and what exactly does this error mean?

```
public class MultiPoint
{
    private double[] testCoord;

    public MultiPoint(double[] coordPt)
    {
      testCoord = coordPt;
    }

    public void printPoints()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < coordPt.length; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println("Coordinate # " + i + " : " + coordPt[ i ]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EchoText
{
  private static String ans = null;

  public static double number, coord;
  private static int counter =0;
  private static ArrayList <Double> coordList = new ArrayList<Double>();
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    mainDeal(); 
    Double coordPt[] = new Double[ coordList.size() ];
    coordList.toArray(coordPt);

    for (Double list1 : coordPt)
    {
      System.out.println((counter + 1) + list1);
    }   
    MultiPoint myMultiPoint = new MultiPoint(coordPt);
  }
   // HELP MENU CREATED BY PROF. BLANDO! I DO NOT TAKE CREDIT FOR THE HELP MENU TEXT!
   public static void helpMenu()
   {
     System.out.println("****************************** LAB 7 HELP MENU ******************************");
     System.out.println("\t\t\tBy Pedro Estrada");
     System.out.println("* This program defines a point in a N-Dimensional space. ");
     System.out.println("    - Each point can have different number of non-zero coordinate");
     System.out.println("    - You may request a random number for any coordinate by typing \"RANDOM\"");
     System.out.println("    - When you are finished entering the coordinate just press the <Enter> key");
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("* Pairs of point are used to create a lines");
     System.out.println("    - If the 2 points have mismatched dimensions, the point from the lower-dimension space is");
     System.out.println("      converted to a higher dimension point with added coordinate of 0");
     System.out.println("    - When a line is created, the line distance is provided");
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("* When you are done specifying points and lines type \"EXIT\" to display final operation statistics");
     System.out.println("* All key words are case insensitive and can be abbreviated");
     System.out.println("* Random number will be scaled between -1,000.00 and +1,000.00");
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("****************************** LAB 7 HELP MENU ******************************");
   }
   public static String userPrompt()
   {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a coordinate: [R]andom: [H]elp: [E]xit to exit program: Enter key  for next point:");
     return keyboard.nextLine();
   }
   public static void mainDeal()
   {

     /** I pulled some code from this website:
      * http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/19024-detect-enter-key-being-pressed.html
      */
      while(true)
      {
      ans = userPrompt();

      if((ans == null)|| (ans.length() == 0) ||(ans.trim().equals("")))
      {
         System.out.println("Exiting...");
         break;
      }
      else if (ans.trim().toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'R')
      {
        coord = Math.random();
        counter++;
        coordList.add(coord);

      }
      else if (ans.trim().toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'E')
      {
        System.exit(0);
      }
      else if (ans.trim().toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'H')
      {
        helpMenu();
      }
      else
      {
        coord = Double.parseDouble(ans);
        counter++;
        coordList.add(coord);
      }
    }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MultiPoint` constructor is accepting type `double[]` as shown here:

```
public MultiPoint(double[] coordPt)
```

However, when you create a new instance of `MultiPoint` you are passing through a `Double[]` type as shown here:

```
Double coordPt[] = new Double[ coordList.size() ];
MultiPoint myMultiPoint = new MultiPoint(coordPt);
```

Answer (score 3):

Java will automatically convert (unbox) a `Double` to a `double` for you, but it will not do the same for arrays.  You're calling your constructor with a `Double[]` and it's expecting a `double[]`.

Comment: I converted all the array relevant code to Double[] from double[] and it compiled. Thank you.